# Stored procedure help for taking IDs and getting result from another table

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

In a table (store100) I have a list of storeIDs that make more than 100sales a day. In another table I have sales. Now what I want to do is for every StoreID in table store100 I want to see how many of product x they sold in the sales table. How do I achieve this? Obviously I don't want to be manually entering the storeIDs all the time so I want it to take all the IDs in the table and compare for sales of x in the sales table.

Table Structre:

```
store100 table:
ID
    lon1
    lon2
    glas4
    edi5
etc 

Sales Table:
ID  |Location|Product|Quantity|Total Price
lon1 London   Wallet   5           50
edi5  Manc    Shoes    4           100
```

So for example I want a query where it takes all the store100 IDs and shows how many wallets they sold.

If anyone has a better idea of achieving please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You will need a join for this

```
SELECT S100.ID
      ,S.Product
      ,S.Quantity
FROM Store100 S100
INNER JOIN Sales S
ON (S100.ID = S.ID)
```

Of course you will still need your where clause if you need it and modify your select to fit your needs.

Comment: So if I wanted to see how many wallets each store sold would the above query work if I added a `where product='wallet'` clause? and it would show me for every ID in the S100 table?

Comment: Correct. You would need to add S.Product = 'Wallet' since we aliased the tables in the join. Long hand would be Sales.Product = 'Wallet' it is just easier to use the alias.